# Logitech MX Master 3 for Mac Bluetooth mouse's pretentious scroll is unreliable with any Logi Options settings

Tags: logitech-mouse

I've spent a few hours to setup reliable scroll behaviour for this mouse (on Big Sur, but i think it is not an OS issue). No luck

Any Logitech Options settings (v. 8.34.91 - latest for now) doesn't give predictable scroll behaviour. At least, my brain rejected to adopt to logitech's engineers idea how it has to be scrolled by my finger.

It is difficult to explain what i'am talking exactly just because it is subjective, but users of this mouse will understand my pain (i guess).

So, any approved advices how to manage this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What i found for now (extra software - [Mos](https://mos.caldis.me/) will be needed)

---

In Logitech Options -› Point & Scroll:

- Disable **SmartShi(f)t**
- Set (or leave) **Smooth scrolling** to `Enabled`
- Set (or leave) wheel mode to `Ratchet`

In Mos -› General:

- Enable `Smooth scrolling` too

In Mos -› Advanced:

- **Step**: `10`
- **Speed**: `3` (it is subjective, but for me more speed gives too many inertia to scroll)

Now my scroll has 4 of 5 stars of reliability in my own rating system...

And if you need speedy scroll just use `Mos` **Dash Key** modifier to increase regular scroll

Comment: wouldn't it be nice that Logitech software engineers study `Mos` app and apply that algorithm for smooth scrolling in their own soft?... hey, Logitech Options programmers?

Comment: Excellent work! This is much better - feels much more "natural". This scrolling behavior is the main reason I got this mouse - I assumed that it had solved this problem - but was obviously very disappointed. Thanks for this.

Comment: @okliv what do you have scrolling speed set at in the Logitech options?

PS you are a lifesaver. I just got this mouse and was worried I would have to return it since the scrolling was so jerky compared to smoothness of scrolling using the trackpad or magic mouse.

Comment: Thanks. That's slightly better. However the scroll on this mouse (MX Master 3S) is just broken beyond fixing.